# Wide table for bulk items addition

Tags: usability

I'm designing a form with which users will be able to bulk add some items into our database. The database consists of 16 columns including the delete button, it looks like this:

[image]

There are obvious problems, for example the "System Type" column is not wide enough to be displayed, it needs to be expanded.

Another problem is that every field is required and people could be adding 20 - 30 items at a time. In this case an expanding panel in columns of 3 probably isn't the most optimale since they have to click to open and close on every item.

**Edit**

The bulk addition is supposed to mimic the spreadsheet the data originally comes from, instead of maintaining code to import an ever increasingly complex spreadsheet, I am trying to do away with the spreadsheet all together as it decreases the complexity over the long run, a user bulk adding items would typically look something like:
[image]

**Edit 2**

All fields are mandatory and have to filed out for each item, the fields which can have default values set along the top are the only ones which are repeated

Do you have any suggestions on how this design can be improved?

Comment: Why is the bulk addition so convenient? Is it that some fields (columns) have the same value (e.g. *Manufacturer Code*)? Can you share a typical user actions when adding bulk?

Comment: see edit should clear that up

Comment: Your first edit got me into thinking - why is it that your users keep the data in the spreadsheets and need to **input it again** into your system. Perhaps it can be done the other way round - they input it into your system and generate, say, a CSV for their spreadsheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea was similar to the one of [colmcq's](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/123977/98561). Now as I can see the default values I came up with the following:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fugjvb.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

You can see a group of "common values" next to the "default values". There you place all the values that **can** be common in the whole batch and the user can chose (using the checkboxes on the left) whether to apply certain common value to the table below.

The *common values* work as follow:

- on **unchecking** the checkbox a respective column will **appear** containing either default value or the value chosen in "common values".
- on **checking** the checkbox the respective column will **disappear** making the table below smaller and simpler.

Now it is up to the user to divide their work in the smart way so the spreadsheet is sorted by most common values

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your design I suggest that users will need to:

Identify what they want to add
Input a sub set of attributes

It feels like some of these fields repeat themselves eg name and alias, manufacturer and supplier code. I think a round or two of user research to see what users need to input.

Objective: minimise some of the lesser used fields so that commonly used, important fields take up most of the visible space.

But do some user research to find out

Comment: I have updated my question to explain that all fields are mandatory and the fields which can have default values which are the ones which can be set as default values along the top

Comment: My post still makes sense. You need to prioritise your interface to give more space to more important fields. The goal would be the user leaves default values for the rarely accessed fields.